# Put elements in two-dimensional list using a loop - Python

Tags: python

My assignment is to create a table using a two dimensional list that stores a Fahrenheit temperature and the equivalent Celsius temperature. Use the following range of Fahrenheit temperatures: 
-10 through 100 in increments of 10.    Thus the temperatures will be: 
-10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50...and so on.

Here is my code so far....

```
fList = []
cList = []
fToCList = [] 


for i in range(-10,101,10): #Fahrenheit range
    fList.append(i)
for t in fList: 
    c = (t - 32) * 5/9  #Celsius conversion
    cList.append(c)
fToCList.append(fList)
fToCList.append(cList)
print("Fahrenheit to Celsius Conversions:")
print(fToCList)
```

I know this technically does what the assignment is asking, but what I would like to do instead is create a two dimensional list that has 12 rows with 2 columns each, with [0][0] = fahrenheit number and [0][1] = celsius number... and so on.

Note: I am only supposed to be using loops and lists in this project. I am trying not to import anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
def f2c(t):
    """Convert degrees Fahrenheit to Celsius."""
    return (t - 32) * 5/9

temps = [(i, f2c(i)) for i in range(-10, 101, 10)]
```

First, we create a function for temperature conversion. The function avoids having to repeat the conversion code elsewhere in the program should you need to perform other conversions in your application.

Second, we use a [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) to create a list of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) where the first element is degrees Fahrenheit and the second element is the Celsius conversion.

Comment: This worked great! I just did this [list((i, f2c(i))) for i in range(-10, 101, 10)], so that it was a list instead of a tuple. Perfect. 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two lists using the built-in `zip()` function:

```
fToCList = list(zip(fList, cList))
```

Iterating over the zip object, you'll get the two-dimensional list you needed.
The zip function takes the values from the given lists one by one and puts them into tuples.
The output you'll get is a list of tuples, where the first number is a Fahrenheit temperature and the second number is the equal Celsius temperature:

```
[(-10, -23.333333333333332), (0, -17.77777777777778), (10, -12.222222222222221), (20, -6.666666666666667), (30, -1.1111111111111112), (40, 4.444444444444445), (50, 10.0), (60, 15.555555555555555), (70, 21.11111111111111), (80, 26.666666666666668), (90, 32.22222222222222), (100, 37.77777777777778)]
```